# Is there a template that can generate static / dynamically bound versions of a class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, static-binding

I'm working on some library code, and I want users to be able to take advantage of static binding if they are able to.  If they are unable to instantiate a class at compile time, I want there to be a dynamic version of the class, so that it can be instantiated at run-time.

For a quick example, say I have a structure template A:

```
template<bool dynamic, int value=0> struct A
{
    static const int Value = value;
};


template<> struct A<true>
{
    int Value;
    A(int value) : Value(value) {}
};
```

These definitions allows users of the library to instantiate A statically, and dynamically:

```
A<true> dynamicA = A<true>(5);

A<false, 5> staticA;
```

The problem with this method is that I have to write the definition of the class twice.  I can think of a few ways of implementing a template that would generate both versions myself, but I can see it becoming a lot of work.  Especially for classes that would use varying numbers of parameters, for example:

```
// It would be much harder to generate a static version of this class, 
// though it is possible with type lists.  Also, the way I'm imagining it, 
// the resulting classes probably wouldn't be very easy to use.
struct A
{
   vector<int> Values;
    A(vector<int> value) : Values(value) {}
};
```

Is there a name for this pattern / problem?  Is there a meta programming library which has templates which can generate both definitions for me?  How do I avoid having to write the definitions of my classes twice?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "static binding" in this context; but what's wrong with `constexpr auto pseudostatic = A<true>(5);`?

Comment: How do you detect whether some particular class is instantiated at run-time?

Comment: Even if dyp's solution is not directly applicable, `constexpr` is probably the key to sidestepping the problem. You might not even need to make `A` a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple mechanism to get the parts that do not depend on the dynamic/static value problem into one single location: put them into another class, let's call it `basic_A`, and let's call the static/dynamic value container you show in the question `value_A`. There are different ways to connect `value_A` and `basic_A` to form the complete `A` class:

1. Aggregation of `basic_A` inside `value_A`. This would mean you have to route every method of `basic_A` through `value_A` and provide the corresponding one-liners in both specializations of `value_A`. This is probably not much of a gain because you have to duplicate all of the one-liners, so scratch that.
2. Aggregation of `value_A` inside `basic_A`. You would either have to make `basic_A` a template too, only to pass the parameters to the `value_A` and provide the correct constructors for both specializations, probably somehow disabling and enabling them via SFINAE. Not a very beautiful and maintainable piece of code, either. The alternative would be to make a common base class (Interface) for the two specializations of `value_A`, have a `unique_ptr` to that interface in `basic_A` and pass the ready constructed `value_A` into `basic_A`'s constructor, at the cost of a virtual function call and poitner indirection whenever you want to access the value. Yuck, especially if `A` is meant to be a small and fast lightweight class.
3. Inherit `basic_A` from `value_A`. The same problems as in 2. apply, regarding constructors and forwarding of template parameters.
4. Inherit `value_A` from `basic_A`. The construction problem disappears, but now `basic_A` can not easily access `value_A`'s value. One solution would be to have a pure virtual function `getValue()` in `basic_A` which the two specializations of `value_A` have to implement. This again has the cost of a virtual function dispatch which might not be desirable for a small lightweight class, but it enables encapsulation, since `basic_A` is a non-template and can hide its implementation in a .cpp file. The other approach would be to use compiletime polymorphism vía the CRTP, which would make `basic_A` a template again.

Here are two examples for the two approaches of 4.:

**4a:** `getValue()` as a virtual function:

```
//basic_a.hpp

struct basic_A {
  int foo() const;
  virtual int getValue() const = 0;
};

//basic_A.cpp
int basic_A::foo() const { return 10 * getValue(); }
```

**4b:** `getValue()` vía CRTP

```
template <class Value_t>
struct basic_A {
  int foo() const { return 10 * value_(); }
private:
  int value_() const { return static_cast<Value_t const&>(*this).getValue(); }
};
```

The template `A` aka. `A_value` for 4b follows. For 4a it is alsmost the same, just lose the template arguments and brackets from `basic_A` since it is a plain class:

```
template <bool dyn, int value = 0> 
struct A;

template <>
struct A<true, 0> : basic_A<A<true, 0>>
{
  int val;
  int getValue() const { return val; }
};

template <int value>
struct A<false, value> : basic_A<A<false,value>>
{
  int geValue() { return value; }
};
```

Comment: `basic_A` as a base class could also be a CRTP template to access the value without a virtual function call.

Comment: @aschepler that's exactly what my last example shows. I'll restructure the answer a bit to emphasize both possibilities before showing code.